# List of all items while adding a new item in VB.NET disappered

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, forms

before i use to see this while adding a new item in VB.NET:

[image]

But now from yesterday things are disappeared and i am unable to see them. What i can see is this:

[image]

Also when i right click on my project and add `Windows Form` it shows the same.... the above one

Comment: try to add new project to so that the above screen will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer :)

Close all instance of Visual Studio. Open visual studio command prompt and type,

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

Press Enter. Let the process be complete and now open visual studio. You will get all missing templates under Visual Studio installed templates.

Answer (score 0):

When u create a new Project, the first will be shown with all items. In Second screen you are just adding a item to the existing project. i.e. Right Clicking on **Project**, and select **Add new Item.**

If you want to see that first screen, Right Click on **Solution** and Select **Add New Project**

Comment: Ok but again when i select add new item, it shows me the second image. How can i add a new form to the project, as previously it shows into the panel and i can easily double click to add it into my project.